# Integrity Constraint Violation

Tags: php, mysql

Why does it show SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity Constraint Violation when most of the inputs are identical as shown below.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $houseno = $_POST['houseno'];
        $stsubd = $_POST['stsubd'];
        $brgy = $_POST['brgy'];
        $citymun = $_POST['citymun'];
        $bday = $_POST['bday'];
        $celno = $_POST['celno'];
        $telno = $_POST['telno'];
        $vaccbrand1 = $_POST['vaccbrand1'];
        $date1st = $_POST['date1st'];
        $vaccbrand2 = $_POST['vaccbrand2'];
        $date2nd = $_POST['date2nd'];
        $question1 = $_POST['question1'];
        $boost1brand = $_POST['boost1brand'];
        $date1once = $_POST['date1once'];
        $boost2brand1 = $_POST['boost2brand1'];
        $boost2date1 = $_POST['boost2date1'];
        $boost2brand2 = $_POST['boost2brand2'];
        $boost2date2 = $_POST['boost2date2'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, middlename, lastname, houseno, stsubd, brgy, citymun, bday, celno, telno, vaccbrand1, date1st, vaccbrand2, date2nd, question1, boost1brand, date1once, boost2brand1, boost2date1, boost2brand2, boost2date2) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stminsert = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stminsert->execute([$firstname, $middlename, $lastname, $houseno, $stsubd, $brgy, $citymun, $bday, $celno, $telno, $vaccbrand1, $date1st, $vaccbrand2, $date2nd, $question1, $boost1brand, $date1once, $boost2brand1, $boost2date1, $boost2brand2, $boost2date2]);
        if($result) {
            echo "Successfully saved.";
        } else {
            echo "There were error while saving the data.";
        }
    }
?>
```

The errors starts at `$boost1brand` up to `$boost2date2`.
When I put `?? ""` from `$boost1brand` to `$boost2date2` it doesn't show any error but it doesn't also show queries in MySql. Below is the part of HTML code for form that connects with `$boost1brand`  to `$boost2date2`.

```
 <p>Are you boostered?</p>
 <label for="once">Once</label> <input value="once" type="radio" id="boostone" name="question1" onclick="displayForm2(this)"><br>
 <label for="twice">Twice</label> <input value="twice" type="radio" id="boosttwo" name="question1" onclick="displayForm2(this)"><br>
 <label for="noboost>No</label> <input value="noboost" type="radio" id="boostno" name="question1" onclick="displayForm2(this)"><br>
     <div style="visibility:hidden; position:relative" id="onceboostContainer">
    <form id="onceboost">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Brand of Vaccine</label>
      <div class="col-md-3 selectContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
     span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
      <select name="boost1brand" id="booster1brand" class="form-control selectpicker">
        <option value="nullvac">Select Brand...</option>
        <option value="COVONAX">COVOVAX (Novavax formulation)</option>
        <option value="Comirnaty">Pfizer/BioNTech Comirnaty</option>
        <option value="Spikevax">Moderna Spikevax</option>
        <option value="SputnikLight">Gamaleya Sputnik Light</option>
        <option value="SputnikV">Gamaleya Sputnik V</option>
        <option value="Jcovden">Janssen (Johnson & Johnson) Jcovden</option>
        <option value="Vaxzevria">Oxford/AstraZeneca Vaxzevria</option>
        <option value="Covaxin">Bharat Biotech Covaxin</option>
        <option value="Covilo">Sinopharm (Beijing) Covilo</option>
        <option value="Inactivated">Sinopharm (Wuhan) Inactivated (Vero Cells)</option>
        <option value="CoronaVac">Sinovac CoronaVac</option>
        <option value="nonevac">None</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Date of booster</label>  
    <div class="col-md-2 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
    <input  name="date1once" id="date1stonce" class="form-control"  type="date" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     <input type="submit" name="create" value="Register with one booster">
 </form></div>
```

Below is the schema.

```
<pma:structure_schemas>
    <pma:database name="vacreg" collation="utf8mb4_general_ci" charset="utf8mb4">
        <pma:table name="users">
            CREATE TABLE `users` (
              `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `middlename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `houseno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `stsubd` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `brgy` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `citymun` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `bday` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `celno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `telno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `vaccbrand1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `date1st` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `vaccbrand2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `date2nd` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `question1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `boost1brand` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `date1once` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `boost2brand1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `boost2date1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `boost2brand2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `boost2date2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
        </pma:table>
    </pma:database>
</pma:structure_schemas>
```

Comment: Please post your database schema. That will show the integrity constraints that you're using

Comment: Please check my schema thanks

Comment: I don't see _any_ validation before you fire off that query. Why trust that all those variables are correct? Even if "it's just me", you make typos: never trust yourself. _Check them_ first, then throw an aggregate error for any bad field, and only if none of them are bad, fire off the query?

Comment: A lot of your input is not in your form code and is not allowed to be NULL. Is it just not included in the example? (firstname, middlename, etc )

Comment: I just followed the tutorial in youtube, and i noticed that every input must be not null.

Comment: But the firstname, middlename, lastname, etc. input works but the booster part it doesnt work